# What type of license do you need to solo a glider in the UK?

Tags: glider, caa-uk-regulations

***What type of license do you need to solo a glider (cross-country) in the UK?***

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glider_pilot_license) states that:

> There is no government-issued licence at present, but EASA regulations will require one by 2015.

This doesn't seem to have updated and I couldn't find anything on the  British Gliding Association (BGA) website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is on the BGA website under (unsurprisingly) [Laws & Rules](https://members.gliding.co.uk/laws-rules/)

> There is no requirement for glider pilots to comply with EASA regulations for pilot licencing until 8 April 2020. The relevant BGA requirements and guidance continue to apply.

You can further follow links to the BGA Certificates, including a Cross Country endorsement:

https://members.gliding.co.uk/library/bga-requirements-guidance/gliding-certificate-endorsements/

In part:

> The Cross-Country Endorsement can only be issued if the applicant has already qualified for a Bronze Endorsement or SPL/LAPL(S) and has the approval of theCFI.

Comment: Wow. You can do that in the UK? Just get in the glider with no license and go? That's crazy! Or am I reading that wrong?

Comment: @Jamiec and what happens in 2020?!

Comment: @Cloud Hold on let me get my time machine. Let me try that one more time being *slightly* less facetious; It'll probably be deferred again as they still won't have sorted out the brexit mess.

Comment: @JuanJimenez you're somewhat reading it wrong. Certification as competent is done by the BGA. Any club wont let you fly their aircraft unless you're certified. Could you go and buy yourself a glider and convince someone to tow you airborne? Possibly. The same is true of powered flight other than you dont need a third party to help you.

Comment: Oh, so there is a "licensing" arrangement but for now it is managed by the BGA. Got it. :)

Comment: It's all very unclear. How many hours do you need to get certified? What are the minimum hours for an SPL? Will an SPL be better to go for now as that will last even after the review period?

Comment: @Cloud honestly, youre right. Its a common theme of aviation regulation. Clear as mud. This is the point you go down to your nearest Gliding club and ask someone who does it every day. There is the chance you can find it (or find someone here who can find it) but theres no substitute for experience.

Comment: ...saying that *all* the requirements are right there in the link Ive provided. You just have to, you know, read.